# Menu for mobile devices jQuery onload problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu for mobile devices, and I need to be onload as hidden not as pulled, anybody can help me? I use jquery/1.7.2 jquery.min.js

```
    $(function() {

        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle(); 
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 300 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });


    <a href="#" id="pull">meniu</a>                     
<nav class="clearfix1">
    <ul class="clearfix1">
            <li><a href="/categorie-produs/femei/"><strong>Femei</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="/categorie-produs/barbati/"><strong>Barbati</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="/categorie-produs/branduri/"><strong>Branduri</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="/categorie-produs/contact/"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and demo of my script http://jsfiddle.net/ss1z6awv/

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the ul element on load. like this below

```
        <ul class="clearfix1" style="display:none;">
```